# http keep alive and ssl

Tags: ssl, https, webserver, keep-alive

generally it is recommended to use low value in keep-alive like 15 seconds or so, so that we can clear idle sockets frequently and serve more clients
Consider we have a SSL connection , so for 15 seconds of inactivity , this connection will be closed , Isn't that ineffective ? , because if client want to fetch some more data after sometime, it has to do SSL negotiation again

I guess I am missing some point here ? Please suggest how https works better with keep-alive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends:

- If the server has lots of resources it is more effective to use long keep-alive times.
- If the server lacks resources it is better to have short times, because each open connection binds resources.
- SSL connection establishment has some overhead and so needs more resources (CPU time).
- But this overhead can be reduced with session resumption, at the cost of another overhead (memory for caching sessions).

At the ends the optimal settings depend on the capabilities of your server, the load etc.
If you have no lack of resources it is best to have a long keep-alive time, because thus the clients will interact faster with your site.

Answer (score 0):

There are several goals you might want to consider:

1. If you are optimizing for latency, then you want to have Keep Alive long enough to capture consecutive requests, to minimize the overhead of TCP and/or TLS handshake
2. If you are optimizing the ability of a single server to scale to serve a large number of users, then you want to have short Keep Alive
3. If you're optimizing the initial page load, which loads a large number of small resources, then you want to have a short Keep Alive

Generally static file servers (optimized for serving many small files that are downloaded together, like CSS, images, JS, that supports an HTML page) should have short but non zero Keep Alive.

A file download server (optimized for large downloads) do not need Keep Alive as the download time dominates over the handshake. You might want to support Range request though to support resumes and parallel downloads.

Latency sensitive requests should have long Keep Alive.